# Moving template part around

Tags: template

I am trying to show new_grid.phtml info under media.phtml or in other words i want to show qty. and dropdown e.g attributes under the image of the product. How should i do that? I am looking at view.phtml and i am lost. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you turn ON ´system > configuration > advanced > developer > Template Path Hints` (and then clean cache) you will see every template name in a red border.

then, when you find the template name, edit in some layout file (could be catalog.xml, local.xml or your custom module.xml as well) and then add your template/block as child ie:

```
<reference name="[parent-block-name]">
    <block type="core/template" name="my.custom.block.name" template="path/to/my/template.phml"/>
</reference>
```

Remember that you need to print you must edit the parent template and add something like this:

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my.custom.block.name'); ?>`

Comment: Thanks for that but in my case, (this)[http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/showImage?img_id=875182] i need the highlighted box to be under picture and i don't know how to.